# Invent Text Syntax

Tags: r

Thank you in advance for reading this Question.
I'm trying to write a general multi purpose function in R to manipulate text in a specific structure.
Let me describe what I want with an example (I'm trying to write `ReadDB` function here):

```
ReadDB <- function(query, ...){
...
}
text = "I'm Mahdi; {[What's your name?] Nice to see you <name>.}"

ReadDB(query = text, name = "Mark")
# output is : I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mark.

ReadDB(query = text)
# output is : I'm Mahdi; What's your name?

ReadDB(query = text, Age = 22)
# warning is : Age Argument is not used!
# output is : I'm Mahdi; What's your name?
```

description of the example:

1. each block in text is surrounded by `{` and `}`.
2. each argument is identified with `<` and `>` on both side.
3. if defined arguments in block are determined by user for the function, then the phrase between `[` and `]` will be removed inside of the block, and `<arg>` will be replaced by the value determined. otherwise everything except what is inside `[` and `]` will be removed in the block.

more complex example is when there is another block inside of a block where we expect to do prioritization same as `()` operator in the equation.

**Update:**

I added more complicated situation with nested `{{`, as follow:

```
text = "I'm Mahdi; {[What's your name?] Nice to see you <name>.{I live in <city>.}}"
ReadDB(query = text, name = "Mark")
# output is : I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mark.

ReadDB(query = text)
# output is : I'm Mahdi; What's your name?

ReadDB(query = text, city = "St. Louis", name="Mahdi")
# output is : I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mark. I live in St. Louis.

ReadDB(query = text, city = "St. Louis")
# output is : I'm Mahdi; What's your name?
```

Note that when default are not given inside `{}` it is empty. therefore `text = {[]I live in <city>.}` is same as `text = {I live in <city>.}`.

Comment: `sprintf` is of use here.  The `%s` substring is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not clear on the description in the absence of more illustrating examples
but this works with the examples shown.   It extracts the default string
into `default` and then removes the { and } and everything between [ and ].
Then it extracts the names in the query and determines which argument
names are not used.  For those it issues warnings.  Then it determines
which names in the query were not substituted and if there are any it 
returns the query with the { and everything thereafter replaced by `default`;
otherwise, it returns `query` with the names substituted.

```
library(gsubfn)

ReadDB <- function(query, ...) {

    L <- list(...)
    default <- strapplyc(query, "\\[(.*)\\]", simplify = TRUE)

    query2 <- gsub("[{}]", "", query)
    query3 <- gsub("\\[[^]]*\\]", "", query2)

    pat <- "\\<([^>]*)\\>"
    names_in_query <- strapplyc(query3, pat)[[1]]

    args_not_used <- setdiff(names(L), names_in_query)
    for(nm in args_not_used) warning(nm, " not used\n")

    names_not_substituted <- setdiff(names_in_query, names(L))
    if (length(names_not_substituted)) sub("\\{.*", default, query)
    else gsubfn(pattern = pat, L, x = query3)
}
```

giving:

```
> ReadDB(text)
[1] "I'm Mahdi; What's your name?"
> ReadDB(query = text, name = "Mark")
[1] "I'm Mahdi;  Nice to see you Mark."
> ReadDB(query = text, Age = 22)
[1] "I'm Mahdi; What's your name?"
Warning message:
In ReadDB(query = text, Age = 22) : Age not used
```

The purpose of SO is not write code for posters. Its to answer programming questions so please provide your code next time and if its too long then the question is not appropriate and needs to be cut down to size.

Comment: That is very clever use of Perl syntax. I really enjoy that.
can we change the code to deal with nested `{{}}` as well?
for example: `text = "I'm Mahdi; {[What's your name?] Nice to see you <name>.{I live in <city>.}}"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me thanks G. Grothendieck for his clever answer.
Though, still his answer could not handle nested `{{` I decided to post my implementation for this problem. hoping other people could use it as well:

```
ReadDB <- function(query, ...) {
arg = list(...)
query.string = query
for (query.arg in  names(arg)){
  query.arg_ = paste("<",query.arg,">",sep="")
  if (grepl(query.arg_,query.string, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    query.string = gsub(query.arg_, arg[[query.arg]] , query.string)
  }else{
    warning(paste(query.arg, " argument is not filtered in query!",sep=""))
  }
} # replace given arguments in the text

find_period = function(x){
  ch =c("\\{","\\}","\\[","\\]","<",">")
  A = lapply(ch, function(ch){unlist(ifelse(grepl(ch,x,perl = F),gregexpr(ch, x,perl = F),NA))})
  ind = 2;
  while (ind<= length(A)){
    tmp = NULL
    for (xind in A[[ind]]) 
      tmp = c(tmp,max(setdiff(A[[ind - 1]][A[[ind-1]]<xind], tmp)))
    A[[ind - 1]] = tmp;
    ind = ind + 2;
  }
  names(A)<-ch
  return(A)
}
p = find_period(query.string)

while (!is.na(p[[1]][1]+p[[2]][1])){
  Block.text = substr(x = query.string,p[[1]][1]+1,p[[2]][1]-1)
  p2 = find_period(Block.text)
  if (!is.na(p2[[5]])){
    Block.text = ifelse(is.na(p2[[3]]),"",substr(Block.text,p2[[3]][1]+1,p2[[4]][1]-1))
  }else{
    Block.text = gsub(pattern = "\\[.*\\]",replacement = "",x = Block.text)
  }
  query.string = paste(ifelse(p[[1]][1]==1,"",substr(x = query.string,1,p[[1]][1]-1)),        Block.text,
                       ifelse(p[[2]][1]==nchar(query.string),"",substr(x = query.string,p[[2]][1]+1,nchar(query.string))),sep="")  
  p = find_period(query.string)
}

query.string = gsub(pattern = " {2,}",replacement = " ", x = query.string) # remove double space
return(query.string)
}
```

Here is a test:

```
> text = "I'm Mahdi; {[What's your name?] Nice to see you <name>.{I live in <city>.}}"
> ReadDB(query = text, city = "St. Louis", name="Mike")
[1] "I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mike.I live in St. Louis."

> ReadDB(query = text, city = "St. Louis")
[1] "I'm Mahdi; What's your name?"

> ReadDB(query = text, name="Mike")
[1] "I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mike."

> ReadDB(query = text, name="Mahdi", Age = 22)
[1] "I'm Mahdi; Nice to see you Mahdi."
Warning message:
In ReadDB(query = text, name = "Mahdi", Age = 22) :
  Age argument is not filtered in query!
```